# Attempting to pass access keys into composer create-project for automated install

Tags: magento2.3, script, deploy, automation

I am writing a shell script in bash (rewriting) that migrates / deploys our magento2 marketplace.

I started off by getting the latest release from github, but that makes it so i cannot use the admin-based web updater (which is the only place I can install our payment processor module because they don't upload to packagist)  I don't want to attempt a sed edit on the package.json to add the repo and access keys, so I'm left trying to use the following command:

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition
```

Of course, this requires I manually enter the access keys.  i attempted to script it like this:

```
echo "a2dthisisnotreale1621a522a 21e9thisisnotreald4a183373" | composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /var/www
```

I get an error stating `You must be using the interactive console to authenticate`.   How am I supposed to do an unattended deploy?  Our shop focuses primarily on continuous integration, and i cannot have our site be down for more than 20 minutes or so.  It seems like every example of installing magento2 is from a non-automated method.

Has anyone tackled this problem?  If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to set the access keys using the **composer config** command just before running the composer **create-project** command

```
composer config -g http-basic.repo.magento.com $MAGENTO_PUBLIC_KEY $MAGENTO_PRIVATE_KEY
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.3.* $PATH_TO_MAGENTO_ROOT
```

Answer (score 4):

As usual, immediately after asking the question, i figure out the answer.

I need to add a file ~/.composer/auth.json with the following:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username":"<your public key>",
            "password":"<your private key>"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need to ensure that i create the folder, chown it to the user executing composer, and execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has trouble with getting magento 2 through composer because of authentication keys issue as given below, then make sure to update your **`auth.json`** with your **Magento Authentication Keys** (generated from marketplace.magento.com) inside your **COMPOSER_HOME** directory and then exit from your terminal / bash / shell and reopen it and try `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento2/` command again to get Magento.

**Detailed step by step instructions are given below:**

**Generate Authentication Keys inside your Magento Makeplace Account**

https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/

**Find your local machine composer home directory by typing the command below. It shows your composer path.**

```
composer config --list --global | grep 'home'
```

In Windows 10 its like

C:/Users/youruser/AppData/Roaming/Composer

**Open the auth.json inside the Composer Home directory (in a text-editor)**

**Update the file with your keys like given below**

```
{
    "bitbucket-oauth": {},
    "github-oauth": {},
    "gitlab-oauth": {},
    "gitlab-token": {},
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "<your_public_key>",
            "password": "<your_private_key>"
        }
    },
    "bearer": {}
}
```

**Exit the bash / shell / terminal and reopen it again and try the composer command to get the Magento package now. It will work.**

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition <your_magento2_install_dir>/
```

BTW my Composer version is 2.x. and am on Windows 10

```
$ composer --version
Composer version 2.0.8 2020-12-03 17:20:38
```

Hope this Helps !